# Validate markup of password-protected sites with W3C

Tags: html, validation, w3c

I have an online app that I am wanting to validate the HTML markup of against the W3C validator.

Problem is users need to log in first to access them.

How do I go about validating these pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this [html validator extension](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/download_090.html). Or by Ctrl-U, copy-paste into the w3c page.

Comment: I disagree, this is totally impossible to apply integration testing to. The view is just as important to test as your app, Why do we use complex testing frameworks like Rspec, Shoulda, and Autotest etc. just to serve the final output as untested html. 

It reminds me of the "super hi-fi" recording artists that record all their music in analog just to ship a super crappy compressed mp3 to their listeners.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer with an automated option if you know one (Selenium maybe?). But tests are just a lower bound; they never prove your app will work. Browsing the app will uncover a lot more corner cases, which this kind of extension easily catches.

Comment: I'm not asking about integration testing.  I'm asking about getting a page validated in W3C if it is behind password protection.  This solution worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: As of January 2013, this extension doesn't work with the current Firefox version (18).

Comment: @ruda Incorrect, I'm using it with the nightlies. I've updated the download link so that it points to the current version.

Answer (score 6):

You have to run the service they provide on your server:

http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html

Thats what we've done, works great.

I think it's best practice to be validating your sites source when it's in development not when its in production... Treat this just like running unit tests. You shouldn't have markup errors go live either.

Comment: +1. Best option if you are worried about the sensitive date on your page.

Comment: Right, but I think it's just best practice to have the app all buttoned up once it time to deploy to production... think about it this way, you don't want to have to redeploy the whole app to the production server risking downtime, dropped user sessions etc just because you forgot to close a tag or something.

Comment: Well-I think we can all agree that most websites are ALWAYS in development-even after they are live :-D

Comment: I mean you have your staging version (often called your development version) and your production version, sometimes called the "live version". I prefer to call them "Development" and "Production" but thats just me.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean markup validation, log in yourself, go to the page you want, view source, and use the [direct input](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean [w3 validator service](http://validator.w3.org/). You can copy paste the html contents into the validator or save the html into a file and upload it. If you have Firefox Web developer extension, it provides a 'validate local HTML' option.

Answer (score 0):

[OmniValidator](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/omnivalidator/) for Firefox:

> Omnivalidator sends the content of the currently visible page to one
>   or more validation services configured in the extension preferences.
>   These validators may be publicly hosted (the defaults are the publicly
>   hosted W3C Markup Validator and Validator.nu) or hosted locally. The
>   results are retrieved from the validators, parsed, and displayed in a
>   collapsable error display panel and summarized with an icon and
>   tooltip on the Omnivalidator button, which can be placed on a browser
>   toolbar. Validation is initiated either by clicking on the
>   Omnivalidator button or by configuring URLs which are automatically
>   validated with one or more validators in the extension preferences.