# How to check restricted access pages for broken links?

Tags: testing

I was googling for tools for checking broken links in a remote web page. The w3c validator seemed a good one. But I am still unsure as how to check for pages which are restricted, i.e. the pages which I can only access by logging in to the site. Can we do that using the w3c validator? If not than is there any other tool for the same?

Answer (score 1):

For basic authentication the online validator will proxy it and prompt you to logon, alternatively see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052580/how-do-you-validate-password-protected-sites-with-w3c).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can specify the login details in the URL: `username:password@url.to.the.site`. This I believe only will work if you are using a `.htaccess` file for logins.